# how to upload file to jersey from angularjs and CORS support

Tags: java, angularjs, maven, jersey, cors

i'm trying to create upload file service. so i was following [the guide  here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jersey/jersey-file-upload-example/) for server side .
and [the guide  here](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2015/03/file-upload-and-sending-data-to-backend.html) for the client side.

but i get that error on the browser

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.200.151:8080/documents/uploadDoc. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8383' is therefore not allowed access.
```

and this error on the server
`192.168.200.151 - - [03/Nov/2016:13:44:59 +0000] "OPTIONS /documents/uploadDoc HTTP/1.1" 200 13 "http://localhost:8383/mamagoose/admin/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36" 3`
.

i know i have issue of CORS support but i have no idea how to overcome it.
i try to edit my pom.xml with this dependency but no luck.

it must be something i'm missing anyone have idea?

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.thetransactioncompany/cors-filter -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

**client side**

```
  uploadfile : function(action, files, success, error){

        var url = webServiceModuleAddress+"/uploadDoc";

        for ( var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append("file", files[i]);

            $http.post(url, fd, {

                withCredentials : false,

                headers : {
                    'Content-Type' : undefined
                    },
                    transformRequest : angular.identity
                   })
                   .success(function(data)
                   {
                    console.log(data);
                   })
                   .error(function(data)
                   {
                    console.log(data);
                   });
       }
    },
```

**server side**

```
@POST
@Path("/uploadDoc")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public String uploadFile(@Context HttpServletRequest req, @QueryParam("callback") String callback,@FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,@FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition contentDispositionHeader) throws JsonProcessingException 
{
    try{
        if(SessionManager.isUserConnected(req))
        {
            String filePath = SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER + contentDispositionHeader.getFileName();
            // save the file to the server
            documentsDao.saveFile(fileInputStream, filePath);
            String output = "File saved to server location : " + filePath;
            return ResourceResponse.getResourceJsonString(output, callback, "true", ErrorMessageEnum.SUCCESS);
        }
        else
        {
            return ResourceResponse.getResourceFailResponseString(callback, ErrorMessageEnum.USER_NOT_CONNECTED);
        }

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ResourceResponse.getResourceFailResponseString(callback, ErrorMessageEnum.FAILURE);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was a hard problem to solve but i will try to help others in case anyone come across the same problem.

the first thing on server side i added the class in my util package

```
public class CORSResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)throws IOException
    {
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = responseContext.getHeaders();
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8383");//TODO:Need to find a replacement
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        //headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://podcastpedia.org"); //allows CORS requests only coming from podcastpedia.org       
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS");          
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
    }

}
```

and then  we need to registered  the class as a provider

`environment.jersey().register(CORSResponseFilter.class);`

This configuration has solved a very big problem for me.
Because even if I could send the file i would not get the session of the user and cannot validate the request and now everything work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error if you are trying to access from one domain to another domain. It's a server side issue. You don't need to add any headers in angular for cors. You need to add header on the server side. The server you are making the request to has to implement CORS to grant JavaScript from your website access.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Refer to this link on how to implement one - https://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled

An example how to implement the CORS, since you are using jersey. http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-add-cors-support-on-the-server-side-in-java-with-jersey/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply...I know the link you added and I tried to follow the section 2.2.
i added the class CORSResponseFilter as is  to my util package and add the environment.jersey().register(CORSResponseFilter.class) but  not luck

Comment: The http://192.168.200.151 is this your localhost server ? or a remote server that you are connecting ? Can you debug CORS filter in section 2.2 of that link and see if that's being captures ?

Comment: 192.168.200.151 is my localhost server. and if i use debug
 i can see the use of the class in every request but i still getting the error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.200.151:8080/documents/uploadDoc. Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."

Comment: Would you mind changing it to localhost from the ip address. I doubt it that would change anything, but how about giving it a try ? Also how are you running the server application ? like deployed in apache server etc ?

Comment: Thanks for the help